# How to move the location of an argument in a shortcut file path

Tags: powershell, parameters, arguments

I've written this script to create a shortcut, its a shortcut to a ps1 file that I want to run as a script. This requires the parameter "powershell.exe -file" Infront of the target file path like this:

> powershell.exe -file c:\users\name\documents\powershellscript.ps1

My script looks like this

```
foreach($filename in $reqshortcutlist){
  $shortcutpath = Join-Path "C:\Users\yo\Documents\Powershell Lab\source" $fileName
$pslaunch = 'powershell.exe -file'
$sclocation = "C:\Users\yo\Documents\Powershell Lab\fixes\$filename.lnk"
$WScriptObj = New-Object -ComObject ("WScript.Shell")
$shortcut = $WscriptObj.CreateShortcut($sclocation)
$shortcut.Arguments = $pslaunch
$shortcut.TargetPath = $shortcutpath
$shortcut.Save()
}
```

My issue is that the file path this creates looks like this:

> "C:\Users\yo\Documents\Powershell Lab\Source\PS CMD Workaround.ps1" powershell.exe -file

As you can see the 'powershell.exe -file' argument is AFTER the file path, is there any way around this?

I've tried to swap the $shortcut.target path and $shortcut.arguments value with eachother so they appear the other way around but this didn't work.
I've also tried using the full powershell path instead of just powershell.exe with no luck.

Comment: yes... the target path must be tha path to powershell.exe and the arguments must contain the scriptpath.

Comment: Hi @Toni , I have tried this as referenced above however the $shortcut.targetpath adds " around the input value and this stops it from working